# In Java, I have a String named string "A"( size 1). Why does string.substring(1) give no exceptions

Tags: java, string, exception, substring

In java, I have a String named string with the value "A". 
i.e. `String string = "A";`

Its size is 1 and we know that characters in a string are 0 indexed. They are represented as a Char array.
Then, why does NOT `string.substring(1);` give me an exception?

Comment: The devil is in the detail.  *"Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the **length** of this String object"*.  A `String` with a single character has a size of `1`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer This should be made the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at code of `substring(int beginIndex)` :

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex) {
        if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
        }
        int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
        if (subLen < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
        }
        return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
    }
```

There is no condition to specify that if length is 1 and index is 1, an exception should be thrown. Infact, a new *empty* string is returned.

`System.out.println("A".substring(1).equals(""));` returns `true` because of *last line in the method*.

Comment: Except, you shouldn't need to look at the code, you can look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)), it states it quite nicely ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Right.. But I find it easier to find *answers* in code. `ctrl+shift+R` and there it is :P

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [JavaDocs for `String#subString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

> Throws: 
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object".

A String with a single character has a size of `1`, therefore `1 == length`

Comment: This is better than the other answers.  "because it's specified this way" is a better answer than "because it's coded this way".

Answer (score 0):

As you can se in the code of `substring`

```
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
```

it will only throw an `exception` if then lenght of the spring is lower then ie begin index.

In your case the begin index is equals the length and thats why you do not get an exception.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Index is 0 and length is 1, right? They are not equal.

Comment: @A1ternat1ve The beginIndex is 1. The parameter in substring(1).

Answer (score 0):

Others have quoted the rule, but I wanted to point out the implications.  If you say `s.substring(n)`, then `n` can be anywhere from 0 to `s.length()`, inclusive.  That means that if `s` has length `len`, there are `len+1` (rather than `len`) possible ways to call `s.substring` with one parameter.  This makes sense, because if you have the string `"abcde"`, for example, and you're using `substring(n)` to get a *suffix* of the string, there are six possible suffixes: `"abcde"`, `"bcde"`, `"cde"`, `"de"`, `"e"`, `""`.

This is helpful in practice, because you can code things like

```
while (<something>) {
    if (s.beginsWith(prefix)) {
    ... do some other stuff ...
    s = s.substring(prefix.length());
        // This sets "s" to the remainder of the string, after the prefix.
        // It works even if there is no more text in the string, i.e. 
        // prefix.length() == s.length(), so that the remaining text is "".
}
```

In my experience, the ability to have things work this way is very beneficial.  It avoids forcing to you write special logic to handle this boundary case, since the boundary case's handling is consistent with the non-boundary cases.